# Surround numbers with a circle using span

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have created an Ionic page that uses `<ion-grid>` to place numbers 1 - 10 on two rows. When clicked, the clicked number's `<span>` is changed to a dark blue to signify selection.

Before adding `float: right`, when this selection would happen, it would only surround a narrow area around the number creating an oval. After adding `float: right`, the clicked number is surrounded with a circle with plenty of space between the edge and the number, as it should be. However, the float is now affecting the grid and has shifted it to the right of the page.

How can I make this work where the grid is centered, but the numbers are not being shifted when clicked?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wmp5w3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple css thing. The span is not a block level element. Set `display: block;` on the span to get the proper blue circles, and set `margin: 0 auto;` to center the spans within the grid elements if you like. No need for the floats.

[Forked your stackblitz](https://ionic-vnu5qv.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `div` containing the grid with the `display` and `justify-content` properties. This makes the items too closely spaced. So, work with the padding of the items.

Your CSS should look like:

```
page-home {

  ion-col span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  }

  .selected {
    color: #fff;
    background: #005189;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  }
.col{
  padding: 15px;
}
.centered-grid{
  text-align: center;
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center;
}
}
```

Add the class `centered-grid` to the div containing the **grid**.

```
    <div class="centered-grid">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row *ngFor="let row of priority.options">
            <ion-col *ngFor="let number of row.priority" (click)="selectPriority($event)">
              <span [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedPriority == number.number}">{{number.number}}</span>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </div>
```